# How to prevent DataTemplateSelector from triggering wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplateselector

Problem with WPF DataTemplateSelector when using SfNavigationDrawer. My issue is to prevent DataTemplateSelector from triggering in certain cases. I have an SfNavigationDrawer with a menu, and in some cases, when I click on a specific menu, I want the DataTemplateSelector not to be applied, and instead, a submenu to be opened. Currently, I'm encountering the error "Must disconnect specified child element from current parent Visual before attaching it to a new Visual." I've tried returning `null` from the DataTemplateSelector, but it causes an error when a template is already set. Please help me understand how to correctly prevent the DataTemplateSelector from triggering in my scenario.

```
    public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate dt1 { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate dt2 { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is NavigationItem navigationItem && navigationItem.Header != null)
            {
                switch (navigationItem.Header.ToString())
                {
                    case "item1":
                        return dt1;
                    case "item2":
                        return dt2;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**.................................**

Comment: What is `SfNavigationDrawer`?

Comment: Please create minimal example that reproduces the issue. Otherwise we have nothing to review and can't help.